# How can I convert a JSON data (from API) into python data?

Tags: python, json, api

Hey guys i´m traying to get data from API stock market.

```
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
print("Recibo mensajes del servidor...")
socket.connect("tcp://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, u'')
while True:
    JSON = socket.recv_json()
    print(JSON)
```

And recive data like this:

```
{'X': {'MDReqId': 'HUB22_1533207696768', 'MDIncGrp': [{'offer': {'OrderID': 
'', 'SettlType': '3', 'MDEntrySeller': '', 'Precio': '435', 
'MDEntryPositionNo': '1', 'SettlDate': '', 'MDEntrySize': 2000.0, 
'MDUpdateAction': '2', 'MDEntryTime': '10:37:56', 'Symbol': 'BA.C', 
'MDEntryBuyer': '', 'NumberOfOrders': '', 'MDEntryDate': '20180802'}}], 
'MDBookType': 2}}
{'X': {'MDReqId': 'HUB22_1533207696768', 'MDIncGrp': [{'bid': {'OrderID': '', 
'SettlType': '3', 'MDEntrySeller': '', 'Precio': '410', 'MDEntryPositionNo': 
'2', 'SettlDate': '', 'MDEntrySize': 24.0, 'MDUpdateAction': '0', 
'MDEntryTime': '10:37:56', 'Symbol': 'BA.C', 'MDEntryBuyer': '200', 
'NumberOfOrders': '', 'MDEntryDate': '20180802'}}, {'offer': {'OrderID': '', 
'SettlType': '3', 'MDEntrySeller': '046', 'Precio': '450', 
'MDEntryPositionNo': '1', 'SettlDate': '', 'MDEntrySize': 2000.0, 
'MDUpdateAction': '0', 'MDEntryTime': '10:37:56', 'Symbol': 'BA.C', 
'MDEntryBuyer': '200', 'NumberOfOrders': '', 'MDEntryDate': '20180802'}}, 
{'bid': {'OrderID': '', 'SettlType': '3', 'MDEntrySeller': '046', 'Precio': 
'433', 'MDEntryPositionNo': '1', 'SettlDate': '', 'MDEntrySize': 10.0, 
'MDUpdateAction': '0', 'MDEntryTime': '10:37:56', 'Symbol': 'BA.C', 
'MDEntryBuyer': '262', 'NumberOfOrders': '', 'MDEntryDate': '20180802'}}], 
'MDBookType': 3}}
```

My question is:

How can I convert a JSON data (from API) into python data?

Comment: use the json lib

Comment: But in real time can i convert this data or i need stop my api and then convert it ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "real time" but yea you don't need to stop the script  and start another to convert it

Comment: `data = json.loads(socket.recv_json())`

Comment: [`recv_json()`](http://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/zmq.html#zmq.Socket.recv_json) already returns a python object.

Comment: `recv_json` returns a Python object (a `dict` in this case). If you want to convert that `dict` into an instance of some class you wrote, well, that has nothing to do with JSON or `zmq`.

Comment: I do not understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have JSON (well, a Python `dict` but Python folks think they're the same thing)!

Run this experiment:

```
while True:
    json = socket.recv_json()

    print(json['X'])

    x = json['X']  # now `x` is the "same" as json['X']

    print(x['MDReqId'])  # this is equivalent to print(json['X']['MDReqId'])

    md_req_id = x['MDReqId']
    print(md_req_id)  # should output `HUB22_1533207696768`
```

Answer (score 0):

The results you are getting from `recv_json` are already a built-in Python type (`dict`). So you could do something like:

`JSON['x']`

Comment: Look:
 while True:
    JSON = socket.recv_json()
    JSON = json.loads(socket.recv_json())
    print(JSON)

ERROR : the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'

Comment: ``json.loads`` parses a string into a Python ``dict``. Given that the data is already a python ``dict``, you can just skip this step. No need to call ``json.loads``...your work is already done after ``socket.recv_json``.